# WPF : How to use many themes files, each one in a separate window

Tags: wpf, resources, themes

When i try to use a themes file in specific window, i can't add button to interface. vs 2012 Designer fire exception. I think there is confusion between themes files. Because i use them in 2 places :

my window contains the following resources section :

```
Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="themes\ShinyDarkGreen.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

and my app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source ="themes\BureauBlue.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source ="themes\ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="themes\GlassButton.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="themes\Mesthemes.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The "BureauBlue.xaml" i used it in main window and i want to use ShinyDarkGreen.xaml in another windows. is there any way to achieve this

My OS Setting are French :

```
Exception : InvalidCastException : Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' en type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.

à MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties.InitCommon(DependencyObject target)
à MS.Internal.Text.TextProperties..ctor(FrameworkElement target, Boolean isTypographyDefaultValue)
à System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.GetLineProperties()
à System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.EnsureTextBlockCache()
à System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
à System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
à MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
à System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
à System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
à System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
à System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
à System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()

InnerException : aucun
```

Comment: Are you having any problems at run time, or only at design time?  The designer has trouble with a lot of scenarios, and it is not necessary indicative of a real problem.

Comment: excuse me i had left office. now i am connected. Well, The exception is fired when i drag and drop a button on designer, so i can't build the window

Comment: Please post the build error and/or the exception that is raised.

Comment: InvalidCastException : Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Windows.Media.Color' en type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'

Comment: Please take  look in my question, i paste the entire excdeption message

Comment: same think when i add button in xaml

Comment: I found solution : in xaml file named ShinyDarkGreen i changed :  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" > to  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" x:Key="ShinyGreenButton"> to eliminate confusion with bureaublue.xaml